# How to allow more datetime format to get validate for Datetime property in Bot framework App

Tags: bots, botframework

As per my knowledge Bot Framework validate only few kinds of date format, How to allow more formats for validation. I am using formbuilder. I want to allow below date formats, How to achieve this.

```
string[] formats =  {
    "d/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MMM/yyyy", "dd/MMMM/yyyy", "dd/MMM/yy","dd/MMMM/yy","d/MMM/yyyy",
    "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/MMM/dd", "yyyy/MMMM/dd",
    "MMM-dd-yyyy", "MMMM-dd-yyyy",
    "d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "dd-MMMM-yyyy", "dd-MMM-yy","dd-MMMM-yy","d-MMM-yyyy",
    "yyyy-M-d", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MMM-dd", "yyyy-MMM-dd",
    "MMM.dd.yyyy", "MMMM.dd.yyyy",
    "d.M.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "dd.MMM.yyyy", "dd.MMMM.yyyy", "dd.MMM.yy","dd.MMMM.yy","d.MMM.yyyy",
    "yyyy.M.d", "yyyy.MM.dd", "yyyy.MMM.dd", "yyyy.MMMM.dd",
    "MMM,dd,yyyy", "MMMM,dd,yyyy",
    "d,M,yyyy", "dd,MM,yyyy", "dd,MMM,yyyy", "dd,MMMM,yyyy", "dd,MMM,yy","dd,MMMM,yy","d,MMM,yyyy",
    "yyyy,M,d", "yyyy,MM,dd", "yyyy,MMM,dd", "yyyy,MMMM,dd",
    "MMM dd yyyy", "MMMM dd yyyy",
    "d M yyyy", "dd MM yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy", "dd MMMM yyyy", "dd MMM yy","dd MMMM yy","d MMM yyyy",
    "yyyy M d", "yyyy MM dd", "yyyy MMM dd", "yyyy MMMM dd"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions I can think off.

First one is the hardest on: you could implement your own `FieldReflector` class and make it able to parse all data formats you mentioned. For this number of formats this may be the best way.

The second one is more of a work around but I used this one before. I created a new variable in my formclass called `DateString` of type `String` and replaced it in the form with my original `Date` variable. The parsing of the string to a Datetime is then completed in a validation method I created. This is probably the easiest way to complete this.